# How can I create custom options for every category?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have 2 categories in Cloud Firestore and the structure looks like this:

```
Categories (Collection)
|
--- 6FbwakI8Jh8Pst79kEV8 (Document)
    |
    --- Category Name (String) => "Cars For Sale"
--- nMWCgN7g9hZsMaeJPLRj (Document)
    |
    --- Category Name (String) => "Cars For Rent"
```

How can I create custom options for every category like the images below:

[Image 1: Cars For Sale](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCmNk.png)
[Image 2: Cars For Rent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDaxb.png)

There are different options for every category and I want to know how can I create something like this using Firebase Firestore inside my categories?

> The [URL](https://om.opensooq.com/en/cars/cars-for-rent) if you want to check by yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution I can think of is to create two separate collections for each type of operation, like this:

```
Firestore-root
   |
   --- Cars For Sale (collection)
   |     |
   |     --- //Options in the first screenshot
   |
   --- Cars For Rent (collection)
         |
         --- //Options in the second screenshot
```

Since a query may always return documents from a single category, then this schema is the simplest one.

Comment: `Car Make, Model, Car Types, Transmission, Color, etc...` options will be array type but what about the type of `Price` option?

Comment: Each field that contains several values, can be added as an array type field, or even better, as a Map, so you can perform multiple whereEqualTo function calls. While the price should be a number.  To perform a query, to find cars in price range, you can use startAt() and endAt() functions. That's it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think you can achieve this, using the following scaffolding. Notice the filters contain `category` ID which maps the filters to the `category`. So this way you could create `n` number of `filters` and `n` number of `categories`.

| collection | document id | document data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| categories | 6FbwakI8Jh8Pst79kEV8 | { name: "Cars For Sale" } |
|  | nMWCgN7g9hZsMaeJPLRj | { name: "Cars For Rent" } |
| filters | nMWCgN7g9hZsMaeJPLRj | { name: "Car Make", value: ["V1", "V2", "V3"], **category: 6FbwakI8Jh8Pst79kEV8** } |
|  |  | { name: "Car Model", value: ["X", "Y", "Z"], **category: nMWCgN7g9hZsMaeJPLRJ** } |

Then you can make use of simple `get()` queries to get data from the collection.

Comment: Okay, I'll try this solution, Thanks.